# Fetch API visitor counter

Tags: javascript, rest

First time poster, long time lurker.
I am trying to complete part of the Cloud Resume Challenge, where after creating an AWS API gateway that links a Lambda function, I need to write some Javascript to call the API and return the current visitor count from Lambda function.

I have searched a number of solutions but they dont seem to work for me, I feel I am close.

Here is what I have for the script

```
          <article>
            <script>
              fetch('https://5cabfxax81.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/')
                  .then((response => response.json()))  
                  .then(data => 
                    console.log(data))
                  .then(response=> {document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = data.count});                                
            </script>
            <p class="subDetails">You are visitor number <span id="counter">loading...</span></p> 
            <p></p>
          </article>
```

And this is the error I get
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWlWZ.png)

Can anyone push me in the right direction? Am I being super stupid here?

Comment: `then(data => console.log(data))` ... means the next `then` is passed the returned value of `console.log` ... which is `undefined` - and `data` is in the previous function, so that's the error - remove **exactly** `console.log(data)) .then(response` and watch as the error vanished

Comment: `            <script>
              fetch('https://5cabfxax81.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/')
                  .then((response => response.json()))  
                  .then(data => {document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = data.count})                                
            </script>
`
Did I understand that right? That does remove the error, but the Visitor counter now says undefined

Comment: because `data` is a number not an object with a property with called count?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
            <script>
              fetch('https://5cabfxax81.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/')
                  .then((response => response.json()))  
                  .then((data) => {document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = data})                                
            </script>
            <p class="subDetails">You are visitor number <span id="counter">loading...</span></p> 
            <p></p>
          </article>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The explanation is in my comments on the question

Answer (score -2):

```
fetch(url, {method:'get'})
```

You can use that so you don't have to deal with empty data or response

Comment: 1. that request responds with CORS headers, 2. no preflight is required, 3. fetch is spelled fetch not Fetch

Comment: method:get is default ... your answer still does nothing to answer the problem